# IdentityServer4 - How to Logout Blazor Webassembly Client from IdentityServer

Tags: identityserver4, blazor-webassembly

i am playing around with Blazor WASM and IdentityServer4. Login/Logut flows invoked from the client are all working well. Used Microsofts documentation found here [Microsofts Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

IdentityServer4 is hosted as a seperate Microservice as well as the Blazor WASM App - two indepented projects.

Now i am facing the problem of signing out from the IdentiyServer4. Invoking the logout from the IdentityServer4 UI doesnt logout the user from the Blazor WASM App. I already read this explenation [signout IdentityServer4](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/signout.html)

```
"oidc": {
"Authority": "http://localhost:8010/",
"ClientId": "demoportal.blazor",
"DefaultScopes": [
  "openid",
  "profile"
],
"PostLogoutRedirectUri": "http://localhost:8070/authentication/logout-callback",
"RedirectUri": "http://localhost:8070/authentication/login-callback",
"ResponseType": "code"
```

}

I haven´t found anything so far to achieve the goal. From my unterstanding it has to be used as oidc connect session managements not front or backend channel policy. But i cant find any useful docs on microsofts site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of reading ive found the answer.

Microsoft descripes the SPA difficulties right here: [Microsoft Handle-Token-Request-Errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-6.0#handle-token-request-errors)

These pointed me to implement on my base component something like this:

```
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();

        var user = (await authenticationStateTask).User;
        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var tokenResult = await AccessTokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();
            if(tokenResult.Status == AccessTokenResultStatus.RequiresRedirect)
            {
                NavigationManager.NavigateTo(tokenResult.RedirectUrl);
            }
        }
    }
```

It works like a charm.

Btw dont forget to include the token when configuring HttpClient.

```
services.AddHttpClient<YOURSERVICEHERE>()
        .AddHttpMessageHandler(sp =>
        {
            var handler = sp.GetService<AuthorizationMessageHandler>()
                            .ConfigureHandler(
                                authorizedUrls: new[] { "URI here" },
                                scopes: new[] { "your scope here" }); 
            return handler;
        })
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>()
```